# How do I Remote Debug with RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have my RubyMine client running on my Windows machine and my development console and server running on a local Ubuntu VmWare because of problems running several of the gems on windows.

There's suppose to be an option to use RubyMine's Remote debugging to support such a setup. But I seem to have trouble running it.

I tried to follow these guides -

- http://blogs.jetbrains.com/ruby/2009/05/ruby-remote-debug/
- http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/remote-debugging.html

But I can't seem to get it working, did anyone ever got a setup like this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please describe the steps what you did exactly at RubyMine's official support forum?
Here it is: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/ruby?view=discussions&start=0

Regards,
Oleg